# In iOS 4.2, how do you search within a web page in Safari?

Tags: mobile-safari, ios

I already have it installed (the gold master), but I can't for the life of me figure out how to search a page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Searching in a page has been added on to the Google (or whatever you use) search facility. Just tap the search field and enter your search term. Instead of launching the search, scroll down to the bottom of the suggested searches and there will be a section labeled "On This Page". Tapping "Find "___________"" will launch the in-page search feature.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's funny, the search window is exactly where I looked (good GUI).   But I was tapping, double-tapping, two-finger tapping, etc. looking for a pulldown, or way to change the function from "Google," which is written right in the search field, to "Search page," "Find Terms," etc.  It never occurred to me to type in the Google field, since it seemed to be clearly indicating that it would just Google for whatever I put there. (Bad GUI).

Answer (score 1):

An unofficial method is to use the "Find In Page" bookmarklet. Available [here](http://www.lifeclever.com/17-powerful-bookmarklets-for-your-iphone/).